# Swift - Set a UI element from outside

Tags: ios, swift, set, uielement

I have this UIViewController

```
import UIKit

class UIViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitle: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And I am trying to set `someTitle` when I instantiate it from another view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.   
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someSTBID") as! UIViewController1
        vc1.someTitle.text = "My Title" // it fails here!!!!!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

The reason it fails at the line above is that I was trying to force unwrapping a nil optional, which is `someTitle`.

Please show me a way to set `someTitle` in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `UIViewController` hasn't been loaded yet, so the `someTitle` IBOutlet will be nil. You got two options:

1. **The easy one:** you force the load of the second `UIViewController`, for example: `vc1.view` is enough and then you set it (**I don't recommend this**)
2. **The proper one:** you let the second `UIViewController` be responsible for setting its own title at the right time. If you need to pass the `"My title"`, you can simply pass it via a function like `configureVc(title: String)`, or by exposing a variable like `var title: String`, so on `viewDidLoad` of the second `UIViewController` you would `someTitle.text = title`.

Comment: Thanks, Peres. I think in the approach 2 that you mentioned, you mean `UIViewController1`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to go into the superclass viewDidAppear, because it should work if you put it into the superclass viewDidLoad(). I hope that helps you and future viewers.